# What happens to point pools when a creature is brought back to life?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature, character-death, resurrection

The main spells that deal with bringing the dead back to life are clear about their effects on spells that they have prepared or uncast.

[Raise Dead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/raise-dead)

> A character who died with spells prepared has a 50% chance of losing any given spell upon being raised. A spellcasting creature that doesn't prepare spells (such as a sorcerer) has a 50% chance of losing any given unused spell slot as if it had been used to cast a spell.

[Resurrection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resurrection) (no mention of non-prepared spells)

> with no loss of prepared spells.

[True Resurrection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-resurrection) (again no mention of non-prepared spells)

> and all of the prepared spells possessed by the creature when it died.

[Reincarnate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reincarnate)

> A character who died with spells prepared has a 50% chance of losing any given spell upon being reincarnated. A spellcasting creature that doesn't prepare spells (such as a sorcerer) has a 50% chance of losing any given unused spell slot as if it had been used to cast a spell.

[Breath of life](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/breath-of-life)
No mention of spells, so assumed that spells are as when creature died.

None of these spells mention any kind of points pool, such as Ki, Arcana, grit, ... What happens to these pools? Since they are not mentioned I suspect they should be as when the creature died, or be treated the same as spells are for that spell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To refill many pools, a creature must satisfy the pool's recharge conditions. For example, a monk's [*ki* pool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Ki-Pool-Su-) refills in the morning after the monk's completed 8 possibly-nonconsecutive hours of rest or meditation, while a magus's [arcane pool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Arcane-Pool-Su-) refills when he prepares his spells. (Other pools must be examined individually.)

Because the various methods of bringing a creature back from the dead are silent about what happens to these pools, *either* the GM seizes upon this silence to make a house rule *or* the creature is stuck with whatever resources he had when he died until those recharge conditions are once more satisfied. This GM recommends the latter.

---

***Note:*** This GM sees death as punishment enough and recommends against, for example, a house rule that empties all a creature's pools upon its death or its return from the dead.